# SensorManager.registerListener (.., Handler handler), example please?

Tags: android, handler

I don't understand how to use this method,

sensorManager.registerListener(SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int rate, Handler handler);

[(Documentation here)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html)

1) If it uses a SensorEventListener, then what's the purpose of the Handler?

2) Please give an example of a handler I could pass to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If it uses a SensorEventListener, then what's the purpose of the Handler?

If I had to guess, it is so you can get your sensor events delivered on a background thread (e.g., a `HandlerThread`). By default, sensor events are delivered on the main application thread, which is fine in some cases.

Comment: can you declare several sensors here?

Comment: can I use multiplt args of SENSOR?

Answer (score 23):

Here you have an example:

```
SensorManager mSensorMgr = (SensorManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

HandlerThread mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("sensorThread");

mHandlerThread.start();

Handler handler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper());

mSensorMgr.registerListener(this, mSensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST, handler);
```

From the source code of android SensorManager's class you can see that the registerListener() extract the Looper of your Handler to create a new handler with this looper where it call the onSensorChanged method.

If you don't pass your handler,the SensorManager will use the main application thread.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, clear and concise. IMHO this should be added to the official docs :)

Answer (score 1):

1) If it uses a SensorEventListener, then what's the purpose of the Handler? 
if you run it on the main thread , and you're doing some heavy calculations you will slow down the main UI to be unresponsive.Always write your long running tasks in a separate thread, to avoid ANR.

Here is an example http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-service-example